# iphone propgramatically read from textfield

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I have created some tables with text fields inside, like in the contacts for the iphone,
(inspired from UICatalog example)

all is working, but how can I programatically read the values of this text fields, I see they have a tag, but how can I read from them (because I cannot use the IB for this as they were created programatically to go inside the tables)(noob here!)

thanks,

Im using some example hello world style where I type on the text field of the table, then click on button and the text typed goes to label,
This sample is to ultimately populate my coredata db from the table textfields
As I said im preatty noob for this so please walk me trough

so when user hit submit, I get the text to the label (and soon to coredata)

```
 - (IBAction) submitYourName;{
lblUserTypedName.text = txtUserName.text;
NSLog(@"received");
 }
```

this is the code for my textfield

```
- (UITextField *)textFieldNormal
 {
if (textFieldNormal == nil)
{
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(kLeftMargin, 8.0, kTextFieldWidth, kTextFieldHeight);
    textFieldNormal = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

    textFieldNormal.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    textFieldNormal.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    textFieldNormal.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];
    textFieldNormal.placeholder = @"<enter text>";
    textFieldNormal.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    textFieldNormal.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;    // no auto correction support

    textFieldNormal.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;   // use the default type input method (entire keyboard)
    textFieldNormal.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;

    textFieldNormal.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;  // has a clear 'x' button to the right

    textFieldNormal.tag = kViewTag;     // tag this control so we can remove it later for recycled cells

    textFieldNormal.delegate = self;    // let us be the delegate so we know when the keyboard's "Done" button is pressed

    // Add an accessibility label that describes what the text field is for.
    [textFieldNormal setAccessibilityLabel:NSLocalizedString(@"NormalTextField", @"")];



}   
return textFieldNormal;
   }
```

and this to show that text field in the table cell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    static NSString *kCellTextField_ID = @"CellTextField_ID";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellTextField_ID];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        // a new cell needs to be created
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:kCellTextField_ID] autorelease];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
    else
    {
        // a cell is being recycled, remove the old edit field (if it contains one of our tagged edit fields)
        UIView *viewToCheck = nil;
        viewToCheck = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:kViewTag];
        if (viewToCheck)
            [viewToCheck removeFromSuperview];
    }

    UITextField *textField = [[self.dataSourceArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.section] valueForKey:kViewKey];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:textField];



return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mako take help from here
Here appDelegate is the object of your Application Delegate class

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.fieldTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

         if (cell == nil) {

cell = [self reuseTableViewCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier withIndexPath:indexPath];
             }

    // Configure the cell.

        UITextField *txtTemp = (UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
    UITextField *txtTemp1 = (UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
    UITextField *txtTemp2 = (UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:3];
    UITextField *txtTemp3 = (UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:4];



                switch (indexPath.section) {
                case 0:
                        switch (indexPath.row) {
                            case 0:

                                txtTemp1.placeholder = @"H/No";
                                appDelegate.HouseNo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txtTemp1.text];
                                NSLog(@"%@",appDelegate.HouseNo);
                                break;
                                case 1:
                                txtTemp1.placeholder = @"Street";
                                appDelegate.street = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txtTemp1.text];
                                NSLog(@"%@", appDelegate.street);
                                break;
                                case 2:
                                txtTemp.placeholder = @"City";
                                txtTemp2.placeholder = @"State";
                                txtTemp3.placeholder = @"Zip Code";
                                appDelegate.city = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txtTemp.text];
                                NSLog(@"%@",appDelegate.city);
                                appDelegate.state = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txtTemp2.text];
                                NSLog(@"%@",appDelegate.state);
                                appDelegate.zipCode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txtTemp3.text];
                                NSLog(@"%@",appDelegate.zipCode);
                                break;
                                default:
                                break;


                                }
                                break;


    -(UITableViewCell *)reuseTableViewCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier withIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


        CGRect cellRectangle = CGRectMake (0, 10, 300, 70); 
        CGRect Field1Frame = CGRectMake (10, 10, 290, 70);
        CGRect Field2Frame = CGRectMake (10, 10, 90, 70);
        CGRect Field3Frame = CGRectMake (110, 10, 95, 70);
        CGRect Field4Frame = CGRectMake (220, 10, 85, 70);
        UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:cellRectangle reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];
        UITextField *textField;
        UITextField *textField1;
        UITextField *textField2;
        UITextField *textField3;

        //Initialize Label with tag 1.

        textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:Field2Frame];
        textField.tag = 1;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:textField];



        //Initialize Label with tag 2.

        textField1 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:Field1Frame];
        textField1.tag = 2;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:textField1];

        //Initialize Label with tag 3.

        textField2 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:Field3Frame];
        textField2.tag = 3;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:textField2];


        //Initialize Label with tag 4.

        textField3 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:Field4Frame];
        textField3.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
        textField3.tag = 4;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:textField3];




        [textField release];
        [textField1 release];
        [textField2 release];
        [textField3 release];
        return cell;
    }
```

Hope you understand...Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:100];
```

Depending on your setup, you might want to replace *self.view* with your table.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the text fields, store a reference to them in an instance variable something like:

```
UITextField *textField = ...
self.myTextField = textField;
[theSuperview addSubview:self.myTextField];
```

Then access the text property on your instance

```
NSString *theString = self.myTextField.text;
```